# visual studio code - debug menu bar gear icon missing

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am not seeing the small gear icon beside the play button in debug menu bar . I played around in settings and set `true` for all options under `Debug`, but still I cant see that gear button.How do I make that available in visual studio code 1.10.2[image]

I was following some steps from [here](http://blog.likewise.org/2017/02/debugging-a-javascript-webdriverio-project-in-vscode/) where i need to click that gear icon.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I am not sure what I did but while playing around in visual studio code the gear icon appeared. If someone has a clue as to why it would have appeared , please share. Heres the screenshot

[image]

Comment: See my answer, right click on far right then select "Run and Debug" and the icon will appear on right, or click SHIFT + CTRL + D to appear.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.

Firstly ensure you have a proper configuration in launch.json.
Then open Debug menu and choose Start Debugging (or just press F5).

It's caused that Debug button/menu appeared.

[image: Debugging in VS Code]

Answer (score 2):

VS Code can be used with single files, or with a directory as a workspace. Within the Debug view, if you only have single files, you'll only get the green "play arrow", and VS Code will try it's best to debug the file.

To get the gear icon, you'll need to open the workspace directory of the file(s) you want to debug (and this is where you want to be).

<strike>That gear icon is for editing a `launch.json` [Launch Configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations), which you don't have one yet, so there's nothing to show (yet).</strike>

If you hit the play icon/green arrow, you'll open the [Command Palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette) menu which will give you a selection of mostly complete launch.json templates for the language and/or toolchain you picked in the Command Palette menu.

Comment: Thanks, WGJ, How to  get the Green Play Arrow Tab back, VSCODE, MAC

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in Visual Studio code, either press (CTRL + SHIFT + D) or right click on the far right and select "Run and Debug".

This usually occurs when you've hidden the option by right clicking on the Debug icon then clicked "hide".

Note: When an error occurs for the first time (usually with new installations or new workspaces/Files created and the Debug (F5) key is pressed, The "Run and Debug" sidebar view will appear the first time. Then you can hide or add it as pleases.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The "Start Debugging" bar was hidden. You can toggle this bar back on by *right-clicking* the **...** button in the Run and Debug tab and then enabling "Start Debugging".

Answer (score -1):

1. Select Start Debugging (F5)
2. Choose Unity Debugger
3. Click Create launch.json file

This should create a launch.json file for you and you will then see the gear icon.