# Debugging control bar disappears in VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I  debug C++ code in VS Code. When I start debugging I get the debugging control bar showing up near top of screen. For some reason it disappears after while and in debug console show "No debug adapter, can not send 'evaluate' " . tasks.json and launch.json are

````
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\Users\\23305\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\mingw32\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\Users\\23305\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\mingw32\\i686-w64-mingw32\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}


{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++.exe - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\Users\\23305\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\mingw32\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}```
````

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42979405/visual-studio-code-debug-menu-bar-gear-icon-missing use this solution